# Remoting set timeout

Tags: c#, .net, timeout, remoting, .net-remoting

[.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) remoting is used in my [brownfield](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownfield_%28software_development%29) application. We decided to set timeouts for our remoting methods.

```
System.Collections.IDictionary properties = new System.Collections.Hashtable();
properties["name"] = Ipc_Channel_Name;
properties["timeout"] = 1 * 1000;

IChannel clientChannel = new IpcClientChannel(properties, null);
ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(clientChannel, false);
```

The problem is that it seems that timeout doesn't work. I checked it by setting `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5 * 1000);` in the invoked code. Is the reason that IpcClientChannel doesn't support timeouts?

How do I set the timeout?

Comment: Any ideas? The question is still actual.

Answer (score 5):

The name of property to set the timeout of the IpcClientChannel isn´t "timeout". The name is **"connectionTimeout"**. See *[Client Channel Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bb397839(v=vs.120))* ([MSDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Developer_Network)). Then it should work.

```
System.Collections.IDictionary properties = new System.Collections.Hashtable();
properties["name"] = Ipc_Channel_Name;
properties["connectionTimeout"] = 1 * 1000;

IChannel clientChannel = new IpcClientChannel(properties, null);
ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(clientChannel, false);
```

Comment: Hi, Jehof. Thank you for you answer. From MSDN: "connectiontimeout is An integer that specifies the number of milliseconds to wait for a successful connection. 0 or -1 indicates an infinite timeout period. The default is Infinite." if you set a connectiontimeout to 1*1000 and System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5 * 1000); in the invoked code, you won't get any exception. It will wait 5 second. I resolved it by modification of the client's code.

Comment: @MegaHerz Sorry, but I don't comprehand. You set connectiontimeout to 1000ms, and server sleeps for 5000ms >1000ms. It definately times out. Why do not you get an exception? You mean it's a bug?

Comment: If you're looking for the **Client Channel Properties** page, it's moved.  It is now on MSDN [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bb397839(v=vs.120)).